# How to add read less button on my code after click on read more?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need some help with my code.

So, I have a "read more" function, but I always have "Read more" text on that button, and I need to make "Read more" - "Read less" text, how can I add "Read less" text to my code, after click?

Here is my view:

```
<span class="small2" style="max-height: 120px"  class="col-md-6" align="justify" >{{ $review->review_message }}</span>
```

Here is my script:

```
$(".small2").each(function () {
    text = $(this).text();
    if (text.length > 200) {
        $(this).html(text.substr(0, 100) + '<span class="elipsis">' + text.substr(100) + '</span><a class="elipsis" href="#">Read more</a>' + 'salut');
    }

});
$(".small2 > a.elipsis").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault(); //prevent '#' from being added to the url
    $(this).prev('span.elipsis').fadeToggle(500);
});
```

Comment: use this -- https://codepen.io/royketelaar/pen/avWxve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try it:

```
$(".small2 > a.elipsis").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault(); //prevent '#' from being added to the url
    $(this).prev('span.elipsis').fadeToggle(500);

    if ( $(this).text() == "Read more" )
      $(this).text('Read less');
    else
      $(this).text('Read more');

});
```

Comment: You're using `$(this)` 4 times in that function. It's probably a good idea to store that in a variable, so jQuery doesn't have to wrap it 4 times.

Comment: Of course, That's not optimized. It's can be better for set **$(this)** in a variable, then use it.

Answer (score 0):

I've made a snippet for your problem, look at it:

```js
var readMore = true;

$(".small2").each(function () {
    text = $(this).text();
    if (text.length > 200) {
        $(this).html(text.substr(0, 100) + '<span class="elipsis">' + text.substr(100) + '</span><a class="elipsis" href="#"> Read more</a>');
        $('span.elipsis').fadeToggle(10);
    }

});
$(".small2 > a.elipsis").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault(); //prevent '#' from being added to the url
    $('span.elipsis').fadeToggle(500);
    $('a.elipsis').text(readMore ? 'Read less' : 'Read more');
    readMore = !readMore;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="small2" style="max-height: 120px"  class="col-md-6" align="justify" >sdfjg oshdlbf pisdb fipvsdb fgiphsdb fpvisdb fpihvsbd vspifb dpifhv sdpihfbv asipfhbv asiphfbv aipfsbvpishfv ishafv pias vfphas fvphs dfvp sdpfdpihf pdahvf psahbf jsabf piabfhidbv iphasb pvichasb dpihvab spvi bapifv aspihvdasjfnd[oashvdasdvc ackb vpasihc vpihfc dfhkzjcnv sdz csdkjcba spdjcn aspidbcv asipdb ashid sdfjg oshdlbf pisdb fipvsdb fgiphsdb fpvisdb fpihvsbd vspifb dpifhv sdpihfbv asipfhbv asiphfbv aipfsbvpishfv ishafv pias vfphas fvphs dfvp sdpfdpihf pdahvf psahbf jsabf piabfhidbv iphasb pvichasb dpihvab spvi bapifv aspihvdasjfnd[oashvdasdvc ackb vpasihc vpihfc dfhkzjcnv sdz csdkjcba spdjcn aspidbcv asipdb ashid </span>
```

Comment: Can you explain what you changed and why?

Comment: I did 2 changes basically: 1) On load I called "fadeToggle" so that initially it shows less.
2) I kept a flag to track the current status so that I can toggle the button text between "Show more" and "Show less". On click I'm updating the button text (based on status flag) and the status flag as well